# Scroll the screen behind terminal

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, touchpad, mouse-scroll

[image]my terminal screen is translucent and  suppose if i open chrome and then  if i open terminal i can see what's written on chrome page while using the terminal window.
This really helps me if i want to see some code on a webpage and then write on to terminal.

So is there any way or any software to scroll the chrome page which is in the back of the terminal screen so that i will use terminal easily without going to chrome and scroll the page again and then comeback to terminal.

if nothing can be done just tell me how to work with touchpad i will create a custom software.

as you can see in the picture it really helps in writing know what i want is to scroll chrome page which is behind terminal without leaving terminal

Comment: If the terminal window is not maximized, you just need to move the mouse cursor to an area where the browser is directly visible and not covered by the terminal. Scroll events always get processed by the window you're pointing at.

Comment: Terminal is maximized . for scrolling on current window we use 2 fingers . i want 3 finger scroll for backward screen

Comment: Your terminal window background is translucent. That doesn't mean it isn't there. The only difference between the translucent background and the white background is that you can 'see' what's behind it, not access it. 
I don't think you can program that out. What you need is for Chrome to be translucent so you can see the terminal window while you use Chrome.

Comment: Do you have _Google Chrome_ or _Chromium_ ?

Comment: i am using Google chrome

Comment: I was working on something, but it would only work on Xorg. Are you using Xorg or Wayland ?

Comment: i am using wayland

Comment: I'm sorry then, for my work-around I was suggesting using libinput-geture with xdotool, which doesn't work on Wayland...